# Command line: monitor log file and add data to database

Tags: linux, perl, unix, command-line, tail

I'm monitoring a log file. Each line has the following format:

```
2012    5       29      14      20              438.815 872.737 -1.89976       -0.55156     8.68749 -0.497848       -0.54559                0       0       6      00       0       0       0               0       0       0       0       0      80       9               0       0       10      0       0       0       8      00       9       0       0       0       0       0       0               2      41       84      0       0       0       1       0
```

As you can see, each value is delimited by a tab.

How can I write a Perl script to take each new line of data (the log file is updated every ten minutes) and insert this data into a MySQL database?

I'd like to do as much of this as possible on the command line.

If I do `tail -f -n 1 ./Eamorr.out > myPerlScript.pl`, will my perl script get data each time the file is appended to?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Does it have to be perl?  You could also do this using just a shell script, along with your database command line client (mysql, psql, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another aproach in bash :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

$|++; # unbuffer output

open FH, "tail -f /var/log/syslog |";

while (<FH>) { chomp; print; }
```

Without Perl in pure shell :

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog |
    while read a; do
        echo "INSERT INTO FOOBAR VALUES($(
            sed "s/ /','/g; s/^/'/; s/$/'/" <<< "$a")
        );"
    done
```

Comment: I recommend using `tail -F` instead of `-f`, just in case your log file gets rotated...

Answer (score 1):

If this is the approach you want to take, you need a pipeline, like:

```
tail -f -n 1 ./Eamorr.out | myPerlScript.pl
```

where `myPerlScript.pl` reads the incoming lines like:

```
while (<>) {
chomp;
print "Handling: $_\n";
```

}